# How to count number of WCF calls on client?

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-client

I have a large number of different WCF client classes (inheriting from `ClientBase`).

I'd like to capture method name and number of times this method was called every time such client is used. This info would be used for performance tuning.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the [`System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms587278.aspx), as it provides a number of interfaces that you can use to intercept calls on the client (and server) side to perform your count.

Note that most of the methods here are operating on the [`Message`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message.aspx) level; WCF at a high level is ignorant of the concept of methods, it dispatches messages, receives them, and then processes them.

However, for the most part, you can figure out from the `Message` what the mapping should be and record that.

Once you implement the appropriate dispatcher interface, you would simply [wire it up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff183867.aspx) to your [`ClientBase<T>` instances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141.aspx).  In the dispatcher interface, make sure you have a way of holding onto the original dispatcher (if you go that route) so you can forward your calls appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Look the extensibility points defined by WCF. Carlo's did an excellent series [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/14/wcf-extensibility.aspx).
Look specifically at MessageInspector.